# LibTIFF failing to save YRESOLUTION and RESOLUTIONUNIT

Tags: tiff, libtiff

I'm using LibTIFF with Visual Studio 2012 (C code), 64bit Windows to produce a 16bit grayscale TIF image. I can open the resulting image in a variety of third-party image viewers and they look fine. My problem though is that I only seem able to write XRESOLUTION. The value I write for YRESOLUTION and RESOLUTIONUNIT do not seem to make it into the header.

```
TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("c:\local\test.tif", "w");
TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH     , 2868);
TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH    , 2048);
TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE  , 16);
TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT,  RESUNIT_CENTIMETER); 
TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION    , 115.0);
TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION    , 115.0);

(That is all for SetFields.. I'll omit the subsequent loop 
and TIFFWriteScanLine calls for clarity, as the resulting 
image "looks correct")
```

When I open the resulting image inside ImageJ (for example) or in AWare Systems AsTiffTagViewer software, I see the following headers described:

```
ImageWidth      (1 Short): 2868
ImageLength     (1 Short): 2048
BitsPerSample   (1 Short): 16
Compression     (1 Short): LZW
Photometric     (1 Short): MinIsBlack
StripOffsets    (2048 Long): 16, 808, 1584, 2388, 3202, 4053, 4889, 5718,...
Orientation     (1 Short): TopLeft
SamplesPerPixel (1 Short): 1
RowsPerStrip    (1 Short): 1
StripByteCounts (2048 Long): 792, 776, 804, 814, 851, 836, 829, 855, 830,...
XResolution     (1 Rational): 115
0               (0 NoType): 
1               (2051838 NoType):
```

So I can see that XRESOLUTION was written properly, but YRESOLUTION and RESOLUTIONUNIT are missing.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:  I tried after using TIFFSetField, to retrieve the values using TIFFGetField. The retrieved values are correct, so it seems that somehow during TIFFClose when things are written out, that they get corrupted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We determined this was a bug but that we were using an old version of libTiff. 
It seems it is currently maintained, 4.0.6 is the latest, which does not have this bug, and can be found here:

http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/